# Does the order of AWK delimiters affects the segmentation result

Tags: linux, awk

my file content looks like this:

[image]

why those actions are different？

[image]

Comment: don't post text as images.. copy paste them to question, select them and click `{}` or use `Ctrl+K` for formatting...

Comment: anyway, the issue is because `-` is special inside character classes... `[a-z]` means all lower case alphabets (depends on locale too, but lets not go into that)... whenever you need `-` to be matched literally, place it at start or end of character class

Comment: or, use `\-` as per https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

The field delimiter `-F` takes a regex and you're passing it something common, a character class for possible separators.

What happens in your second case is that in a character class, the `-` has the special meaning of defining a range when not as first or last entry: `[a-z]` means any character between a and z, so your second option `[ -:]` means "Use any character between space and : as separator, if you wish to see which characters this relies to you can check the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). One workaround is to espace it like `[ \-:]` but it's usually better to place it in a place where it doesn't have a special meaning like first or last place, the only character really needing to be escaped in a character class is `]` as its place can't tell if it's closing the class or if it is part of it.

The resulting character set to split on is `!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:`